# Removing duplicate objects across several List<> objects using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a couple of classes that look like this (simplified for SO):

```
public class Result
{
    pubic List<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
}

public class Review
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

What I'm starting with is a `List<Result>` object. Each of the "Result" objects in the list obviously has another List property within it. Within each "Result" object, its list of Reviews will never have a duplicate "Name" property. However, there is an expected situation where there WILL be duplicate "Name" properties across all Result objects in the list.

For example:

```
var results = new List<Result>();

var result1 = new Result();
result1.Reviews = new List<Review>();
result1.Reviews.Add(new Review { Name = "ABC", Amount = 5 });
result1.Reviews.Add(new Review { Name = "DEF", Amount = 4 });
results.Add(result1);

var result2 = new Result();
result2.Reviews = new List<Review>();
result2.Reviews.Add(new Review { Name = "ABC", Amount = 1 });
result2.Reviews.Add(new Review { Name = "WRA", Amount = 4 });
results.Add(result2);

var result3 = new Result();
result3.Reviews = new List<Review>();
result3.Reviews.Add(new Review { Name = "ABC", Amount = 2 });
result3.Reviews.Add(new Review { Name = "ARA", Amount = 4 });
results.Add(result3);
```

So, you can see that across the list of results, the name "ABC" is duplicated in the list of Reviews. What I need to do is to write a LINQ query, operating on the `results` object that will remove all of the duplicate Review objects from the child lists EXCEPT for the highest one. So in this case, result2 and result3 would both have their "ABC" reviews completely removed from the list.

Any suggestions on how do do this using LINQ? I'm looking for solutions on my own as well, just figured I'd post here to see if it's faster than figuring it out on my own. :)

Comment: Not really sure, but what about `var query = result1.Reviews.Concat(result2.Reviews).Concat(result3.Reviews).GroupBy(r => r.Name).Select(grp => new Review { Name = grp.Key, Amount = grp.Max(r => r.Amount)});`

Comment: There are an undefined number of result objects. I wouldn't want to hard code it like that, but thank you.

Comment: in that case you can use `SelectMany` to get a flattened list of `Review`, something like `List<Review> reviewList = list.SelectMany(r => r.Reviews).ToList();` where your `list` is `List<Result>`

Comment: By "highest" do you mean the `Review` with the largest `Amount`?

Answer (score 0):

don't use a public property for `Reviews`, but a private one. Then provide your own `add()` Method and do either insert or replace elements.

Modify the `Equals` method of your Result, so Results are threaded "equal", when the name match. (this is not correct, but makes `contains()` and `indexOf()` work in the way we want it to work when checking for item existence):

```
public class Review
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(System.Object obj)
        {
            // If parameter is null return false.
            if (obj == null)
            {
                return false;
            }


            Review r = obj as Review;
            if ((System.Object)r == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            //only compare on the name.
            return Name.Equals(r.Name);
        }
    }
```

Now, the result and the add method:

```
class Result
    {
        private List<Review> _Reviews = new List<Review>();
        public List<Review> Reviews { get { return _Reviews; } }

        public void Add(Review r)
        {
            if (_Reviews.Contains(r))
            {
                //check if difference on Amount
                int index = _Reviews.IndexOf(r);
                Review currentReview = _Reviews[index];

                if (currentReview.Amount < r.Amount)
                {
                    //replace
                    _Reviews.RemoveAt(index);
                    _Reviews.Add(r);
                }
                //else keep existing
            }
            else
            {
                //Add
                _Reviews.Add(r);
            }
        }
    }
```

Finally you can add every Review to the *same* result without taking care of anything:

```
var result = new Result();

            result.Add(new Review { Name = "ABC", Amount = 5 });
            result.Add(new Review { Name = "DEF", Amount = 4 });
            result.Add(new Review { Name = "ABC", Amount = 1 });
            result.Add(new Review { Name = "WRA", Amount = 4 });
            result.Add(new Review { Name = "ABC", Amount = 2 });
            result.Add(new Review { Name = "ARA", Amount = 4 });

            foreach (Review r in result.Reviews)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(r.Name + ": " + r.Amount);
            }
```

No matter in which order you provide the add-calls, the elements contained are:

```
ABC:5 
DEF:4
WRA:4
ARA:4
```

(if required, sort by name)

Answer (score 0):

This will give you an Enumerable of all the reviews with filtered to exclude everything but the max duplicates.  You can then process them however you like.

```
results
    .SelectMany(l => l.Reviews) // flattens the lists
    .GroupBy(r => r.Name)       // groups all reviews of the same thing together
    .Select(g => new Review {Name = g.Key, Amount = g.Max(x => x.Amount)})  // select only the highest of each group
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, if you want to get the list of `Result`s:

```
List<Result> newList = results.SelectMany(res => res.Reviews.Select(r => new { Result = res, Review = r }))
        .GroupBy(pair => pair.Review.Name)
        .Select(grp => grp.First())
        .GroupBy(pair => pair.Result, pair => pair.Review)
        .Select(reviews =>
                {
                    // Here you can create new Result object of use the original one
                    Result result = reviews.Key; // Here is original Result object
                    result.Reviews = reviews.ToList(); // Replacing Reviews list with the filtered one
                    return result;
                })
        .ToList();
```

The drawback of this query is that it removes Results without Reviews.

If you don't need original Result object, then you can use simplified version of the query:

```
List<Result> newList = results.SelectMany(res => res.Reviews)
                              .GroupBy(r => r.Name)
                              .Select(grp => grp.First())
                              .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Verbose solution but it will produce your requirements:

```
var rev = results.SelectMany(r => r.Reviews).GroupBy(n => n.Name).Where(c => c.Count() > 1);

foreach (var item in rev)
{
   Review review = results.SelectMany(r => r.Reviews).First(x => x.Name == item.Key);
   results.ForEach(r => r.Reviews.RemoveAll(re => re.Name == item.Key && !re.Equals(review)));
}
```

This will remove all the duplicates exept the first occurence.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SelectMany` to get a flat sequence of all of the reviews from all of the results, you can group those by name, filter out the groups that have more than one item, select out all of the items after the first, and then remove all of those reviews from their result.

Doing all of this is more convenient in query syntax than in method syntax.

```
var query = from result in results
            from review in result.Reviews
            group new { result, review } by review.Name into matches
            where matches.Count() > 1
            from match in matches
                .OrderByDescending(match => match.review.Amount)
                .Skip(1)
            select match;

foreach (var match in query)
    match.result.Reviews.Remove(match.review);
```